# How to run TeX from the command line interface in Linux

Tags: compiling, linux, options

Even though I can find this command hiding somewhere on the internet, I though it might be useful to have it up here for the LaTeX community in general.

How does one run TeX from the command line interface (Terminal) in Linux?
Are there any required parameters?
What if the command is part of a bigger script, how does the script know when the TeX processing is done to continue with any subsequent actions needed?
Is there a clear manual for this somewhere?

---

A starting point might be:

```
pdflatex [options] filename.tex
latex [options] filename.tex
xelatex [options] filename.tex
```

Comment: Hi! In my opinion, your question does not seem to me to be really good. There are couple reasons: (1) You answer the question in the question text. (2) You obviously somehow know the answer and you don't ask "for yourself", but in the current shape, I don't think it can help anybody. (3) Please note that most of the "broad" questions like this one are posted after some discussion in the community, usually on [meta] or in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends), in both of which you're most welcome ;) (Notice that I didn't downvote it since I think -1 is enough.)

Comment: @tohecz I need to mention how much I like what you have done here. Most people do not take the time to comment when they downvote a question. Without even downvoting it you explained very well why you think the question is bad and in such a friendly manner! I wish this happened more often.

Comment: Have to tried `man pdftex`? This is Unix, you know.

Comment: I tried XeLaTeX document and got `kpathsea: Running mktexfmt XeLaTeX.fmt I can't find the format file `XeLaTeX.fmt'!` and trying to use man XeLaTeX I got `no manual entry for XeLaTeX` so for people are starting to learn how to use TeX & friends without a GUI, answers to this would be very useful

Comment: For a question considered by some to be 'not really good' it just received over 10 000 views, so it seems that a lot of people are interested in this at least.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're right: `latex filename.tex` and the other above command are means to run a flavor of TeX from the command line.

They don't really require parameters, but you could also have a look at the configuration of GUI software like Texmaker, or type in the command line `latex --help` to show the complete list of available options. For example, the option `-interaction=nonstopmode` makes latex not stopping on every error...

These programs run in a single shot: they will not take action. For that, in Linux, you could write a Makefile that will arrange the required compilation steps, as shown [here](http://www.acoustics.hut.fi/u/mairas/UltimateLatexMakefile/) or [here](http://www.fclose.com/b/linux/1643/a-simple-makefile-for-latex/).

For the manual, you could try `man latex`, but I don't think that it is a good answer or question. The above commands run Latex/Pdflatex/... the same ways that a GUI editor will do.

Answer (score 2):

In order for this to work, you need to make sure the TeX binaries are in your path, and that the version you want to run is in your path before any other binaries with the same names.  If you install TeX from your OS package manager, it should set this up for you.

However, many distros package an old version of TeX Live, and you might need to [install a newer one.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)  In that case, you will need to set up your `PATH` for the binaries to work, as well as your `MANPATH` and `INFOPATH` for the command-line documentation.

To make the TeX live installer work properly, the commands you must add to your login scripts are similar to

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
export PATH
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH
export INFOPATH
MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH
export MANPATH
```

To enable them for all users, save them to a file, name it something like `/etc/profile.d/texlive.sh`, and `chmod 755`.  To enable them only for your own user account, you would want to save them to `~/.bash_profile` as well as `~/.bashrc`, or to a single file that you `source` from both of these.  (And if you changed your login shell, you don’t need these instructions.)

I personally set up one more command, a shell alias to update my TeX installation.  I have TeX Live installed as the system user `tex`, which in theory means that an exploit in TeX Live at least should not get `root`.

```
alias update-tex='sudo -u tex -E $(which tlmgr) update --self --all'
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you install the latex package by executing the following command :

```
sudo apt install texlive-latex-base
```

Second, execute :

```
latex Filename.tex
```

Comment: And for all the beginners reading this: you probably have `latexmk` or `arara` installed, use one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Use `makefile` and have more freedom. An example would be:

```
# Generate your PDF
%.pdf : %.tex
        @echo '.........: pdflatex running pass 1...'
        pdflatex $< -o $@ 2>&1 | tee errors.err
        @echo '.........: bibtex running...'
        bibtex $(basename $<) 2>&1 | tee errors.err
        @echo '.........: pdflatex running pass 2...'
        pdflatex $< -o $@ 2>&1 | tee errors.err
        @echo '.........: pdflatex and bibtex run finished.'
# Clean temp files
clean :
        rm -f *.o errors.err
        rm -f *.aux *.bbl *.blg *.log *.out
        rm -f *.synctex.gz
        rm -f BUILD
        @echo
```

## Command: `$ make article.pdf`

This will do:

- `pdflatex article.tex -o article.pdf` : pass 1 to generate your PDF
- `bibtex article` : this will update your bibliography
- `pdflatex article.tex -o article.pdf` : after updating bibliography you need a pass 2 to update your PDF

## Command: `$ make clean`

This command will remove all temporary files generated by the compilation process.

Comment: Note that `pdflatex article.tex -o article.pdf` doesn't do what you think it does!  It typesets `article.tex` (which is by default saved to a PDF named `article.pdf`) then it adds the string `-o article.pdf` to be typeset at the end, but it does not appear there because the `\end{document}` stops processing before that.