# Opening compiled document in Android

Tags: output, android

This is my third question regarding LaTeX on Android. 
In first question ([Installing Latex on Android](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522635/installing-latex-on-android)) I learnt to install termux app from Google Play Store. In second question ([How to compile tex file using Termux Android](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522702/how-to-compile-tex-file-using-termux-android?noredirect=1#comment1321981_522702)) I learnt some basic stuffs to fix some technical issues. Finally I received the following output.

```
Output written on abc.pdf (1 page, 20412 bytes).
Transcript written on abc.log.
```

I searched for this file in file manager but couldn't find. I don't know how to open this. I shall admit that I am not sure whether I am successful. I don't know where this file is stored. So please help me.

This is my terminal transcript

```
Welcome to Termux!

Wiki:            https://wiki.termux.com
Community forum: https://termux.com/community
Gitter chat:     https://gitter.im/termux/term
ux
IRC channel:     #termux on freenode

Working with packages:

 * Search packages:   pkg search <query>
 * Install a package: pkg install <package>
 * Upgrade packages:  pkg upgrade

Subscribing to additional repositories:

 * Root:     pkg install root-repo
 * Unstable: pkg install unstable-repo
 * X11:      pkg install x11-repo

Report issues at https://termux.com/issues

$ pdflatex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20
 (TeX Live 2019/Termux) (preloaded format=pdfl
atex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**/storage/emulated/0/download/abc.tex
entering extended mode
(/storage/emulated/0/download/abc.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive
/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/articl
e.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Stand
ard LaTeX document class

(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive
/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12
.clo)) (./abc.aux) [1{/data/data/com.termux/fi
les/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/
fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./abc.au
x) )</data/data/com.termux/files/
usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/publi
c/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></data/da
ta/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-di
st/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmr17.pfb>
Output written on abc.pdf (1 page, 20412 bytes
).
Transcript written on abc.log.
$
```

Comment: Did you check `storage/emulated/0/download/` (since `.tex` is there)?

Comment: @Sigur Yes. It is not there

Comment: @Sigur Is there any way to open document using termux by itself?

Comment: Sorry, I can not help. I never used it. I'm just following the discussion here. Lets wait for experts.

Comment: @Sigur  It is okey. 

Comment: @Sigur It is solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I am successful in using latex on Android. Thanks to 
https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Sharing_Data Using the command

```
termux-open abc.pdf --send
```

I was able to send file to Google drive. Thanks a lot for all members who have helped me in this venture.

Edit: I am not very good at explaining things. So I just recorded all the steps from installing Termux to opening compiled document. You may check them here
https://youtu.be/kGz1MGwwcE0
https://youtu.be/tMb_XcinN8U

Comment: So, now, maybe you can use some kind of *search* to find the pdf file. I found this: https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Sharing_Data

Comment: @Sigur Thank you. I will check it.

Comment: This is more of an Android question than a TeX question though. See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218354/how-do-i-access-home-storage-outside-of-termux-with-a-file-explorer (easiest solution would be to cd into a subdirectory of sdcard and compile from there)

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try [Termux-setup-storage](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-setup-storage)