# Is there a Latex app for Android?

Tags: overleaf, android

Is there a Latex app for Android? I know that I can use Overleaf, but are there any others?

I have found [VerbTex](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=verbosus.verbtex&hl=es_419&gl=US), is that useful?

Comment: I think that Overleaf is the best option.

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20227/offline-latex-editor-and-compiler-for-android

Comment: termux is a terminal emulator. You can install TeXLive and an Editor from your choice. Emacs for instance.

Comment: Do you really want to type stuff like `x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}` using a phone keyboard?

Comment: @Gaussler the virtual keyboard on a 10" android tablet is not so much smaller than the real keyboard on a 12" notebook

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522635/installing-latex-on-android

Comment: I used VerbTeX a long time ago, and it worked for me in a pinch.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, if it works for you, fine. But to me, it’s not really about size. I can type a million times faster on a physical keyboard than on a virtual one, even if it has the same size as the physical one.

Answer (score 6):

I never tried, but it seems that [Termux](https://termux.com/) let you install a TeXLive: https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/TeX_Live.

I use Termux for editing files and preparing little python program (Python3 works like a charm), so I suppose it will work. Now, I never tried to fire up a graphical --- meaning X --- connection.

Comment: Texlive in Termux works great. It is best (on a phone) to avoid a full Texlive install!

I'm not going to go into details of installing texlive but here are some hints for steps to install using the actual texlive installer (so you can select what schemes and packages you want). Do the following in order:
1) pkg install unstable-repo
2) pkg install texlive-installer
3) termux-install-tl
Then add bin/texlive to path

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

1. Of course `VerbTeX`    (**Free**)
2. `Tex Writer-Latex On the Go`   (**not Free**)
3. `MaTeX-Markdown to LaTex Text Editor`   (**Free**)
4. Not sure but `Hemibit TeX/LaTeX Writer` (**not Free**)
5. Not sure but `TexPortal` (**not Free**)

Answer (score 2):

SNIP allows you to transform a written math formula into latex code. It Works very well.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mathpix.snip&hl=pt_BR&gl=US

https://mathpix.com/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could package it into a native app with WebAssembly?

I saw this: https://github.com/SwiftLaTeX/SwiftLaTeX

Integrate a PDF reader and you're good to go ;)

PS: If you want to actually build this project feel free to PM me and we can start collab on GitHub (Apache-2.0 OR MIT) is my preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [proot-distro](https://github.com/termux/proot-distro) with Termux. With this, you can install a chroot-based Linux distribution. So you can install the texlive (full or other schemes).
For the editor, I highly recommend [code-server](https://coder.com/docs/code-server/latest/termux) (vscode's web version), it can be installed on proot-distro.

Comment: Welcome. // I think it‘s a way to do it. However, it will probably not feel like having an App doing Latex, at least not right-away.